# what is &rsaquo in php (wordpress)?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am a beginner in programming and php.
I am trying to understand how this form works. usually when the submit button in the form is clicked the action will be assigned to some filename.php to get processed by post or get method. but i donot know how this form is processed (i can understand form fields are using few functions from other php files)
In particular i want to understand this

```
<input type="button" name="goback" class="btn_orange" value="<?php _e( 'Go back', APP_TD);?>" onclick="history.back()" />
<input type="submit" name="step2" id="step2" class="btn_orange" value="<?php _e( 'Continue &rsaquo;&rsaquo;', APP_TD ); ?>" />
```

This is one of the file from wordpress theme
I am copying the full code of that file containing form.

```
    global $current_user, $wpdb;
    $error_msg = false;
    // check to see if there are images included
    // then valid the image extensions
    if ( ! empty( $_FILES['image'] ) )
        $error_msg = cp_validate_image();
    // check to see is ad pack specified for fixed price option
    if ( $cp_options->price_scheme == 'single' && cp_payments_is_enabled() && ! isset(       $_POST['ad_pack_id'] ) )
        $error_msg[] = __( 'Error: no ad pack has been defined. Please contact the site administrator.', APP_TD );
    $error_msg = apply_filters( 'cp_listing_validate_fields', $error_msg );
    // images are valid
    if ( ! $error_msg ) {
        // create the array that will hold all the post values
        $postvals = array();
        // delete any images checked
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['image'] ) )
            cp_delete_image();
        // update the image alt text
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['attachments'] ) )
            cp_update_alt_text();
        // upload the images and put into the new ad array
        if ( ! empty( $_FILES['image'] ) )
            $postvals = cp_process_new_image();
            if ( ! empty( $_POST['app_attach_id'] ) )
            $postvals['app_attach_id'] = $_POST['app_attach_id'];
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['app_attach_title'] ) )
            $postvals['app_attach_title'] = $_POST['app_attach_title'];
        // put all the posted form values into an array
        foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value ) {
            if ( ! is_array( $_POST[ $key ] ) )
                $postvals[ $key ] = appthemes_clean( $value );
            else
                $postvals[ $key ] = array_map( 'appthemes_clean', $value );
        }
        // keep only numeric, commas or decimal values
        $postvals['cp_price'] = ( empty( $_POST['cp_price'] ) ) ? '' : appthemes_clean_price( $_POST['cp_price'] );
        if ( isset( $postvals['cp_currency'] ) && ! empty( $postvals['cp_currency'] ) )
            $price_curr = $postvals['cp_currency'];
        else
            $price_curr = $cp_options->curr_symbol;
        // keep only values and insert/strip commas if needed
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['tags_input'] ) ) {
            $postvals['tags_input'] = appthemes_clean_tags( $_POST['tags_input'] );
            $_POST['tags_input'] = $postvals['tags_input'];
        }
        // store the user IP address, ID for later
        $postvals['cp_sys_userIP'] = appthemes_get_ip();
        $postvals['user_id'] = $current_user->ID;
        $ad_pack_id = ( isset( $_POST['ad_pack_id'] ) ) ? appthemes_numbers_only( $_POST['ad_pack_id'] ) : false;
        if ( $ad_pack_id )
            $postvals['pack_duration'] = cp_get_ad_pack_length( $ad_pack_id );
        $coupon = false;
        if ( cp_payments_is_enabled() ) {
            // see if the featured ad checkbox has been checked
            if ( isset( $_POST['featured_ad'] ) ) {
                $postvals['featured_ad'] = $_POST['featured_ad'];
                // get the featured ad price into the array
                $postvals['cp_sys_feat_price'] = $cp_options->sys_feat_price;
            }
            // calculate the ad listing fee and put into a variable
            $postvals['cp_sys_ad_listing_fee'] = cp_ad_listing_fee($_POST['cat'], $ad_pack_id, $postvals['cp_price'], $price_curr);
            // calculate the total cost of the ad
            if ( isset( $postvals['cp_sys_feat_price'] ) )
                $postvals['cp_sys_total_ad_cost'] = cp_calc_ad_cost($_POST['cat'], $ad_pack_id, $postvals['cp_sys_feat_price'], $postvals['cp_price'], $coupon, $price_curr);
            else
                $postvals['cp_sys_total_ad_cost'] = cp_calc_ad_cost($_POST['cat'], $ad_pack_id, 0, $postvals['cp_price'], $coupon, $price_curr);
            //UPDATE TOTAL BASED ON MEMBERSHIP
            //check for current users active membership pack and that its not expired
            if ( ! empty( $current_user->active_membership_pack ) && appthemes_days_between_dates( $current_user->membership_expires ) > 0 ) {
                    $postvals['cp_membership_pack'] = get_pack( $current_user->active_membership_pack );
                    //update the total cost based on the membership pack ID and current total cost
                    $postvals['cp_sys_total_ad_cost'] = get_pack_benefit( $postvals['cp_membership_pack'], $postvals['cp_sys_total_ad_cost'] );
                    //add featured cost to static pack type
                    if ( isset( $postvals['cp_sys_feat_price'] ) && in_array( $postvals['cp_membership_pack']->pack_type, array( 'required_static', 'static' ) ) )
                        $postvals['cp_sys_total_ad_cost'] += $postvals['cp_sys_feat_price'];
            }
        }
        // prevent from minus prices if bigger discount applied
        if ( ! isset( $postvals['cp_sys_total_ad_cost'] ) || $postvals['cp_sys_total_ad_cost'] < 0 )
                $postvals['cp_sys_total_ad_cost'] = 0;
        // now put the array containing all the post values into the database
        // instead of passing hidden values which are easy to hack and so we
        // can also retrieve it on the next step
        $option_name = 'cp_' . $postvals['oid'];
        update_option( $option_name, $postvals );
                 ?>
        <div id="step2"></div>
        <h2 class="dotted"><?php _e( 'Review Your Listing', APP_TD ); ?></h2>
        <img src="<?php echo appthemes_locate_template_uri('images/step2.gif'); ?>" alt="" class="stepimg" />
        <?php do_action( 'appthemes_notices' ); ?>
        <form name="mainform" id="mainform" class="form_step" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <ol>
                    <?php
                        // pass in the form post array and show the ad summary based on the formid
                        echo cp_show_review( $postvals );
                    ?>
                </ol>
                <div class="pad10"></div>
                <div class="license"><?php cp_display_message( 'terms_of_use' ); ?></div>
                <div class="clr"></div>
                <p class="terms">
                    <?php _e( 'By clicking the proceed button below, you agree to our terms and conditions.', APP_TD ); ?>
                    <br />
                    <?php _e( 'Your IP address has been logged for security purposes:', APP_TD ); ?> <?php echo $postvals['cp_sys_userIP']; ?>
                </p>

                <p class="btn2">
                        <input type="button" name="goback" class="btn_orange" value="<?php _e( 'Go back', APP_TD ); ?>" onclick="history.back()" />
                        <input type="submit" name="step2" id="step2" class="btn_orange" value="<?php _e( 'Continue &rsaquo;&rsaquo;', APP_TD ); ?>"                       />
                </p>

                <input type="hidden" id="oid" name="oid" value="<?php echo $postvals['oid']; ?>" />

        </form>


        <div class="clear"></div>

               <?php

                 } else {

                ?>

        <h2 class="dotted"><?php _e( 'An Error Has Occurred', APP_TD ); ?></h2>

        <div class="thankyou">
            <p><?php echo appthemes_error_msg( $error_msg ); ?></p>
            <input type="button" name="goback" class="btn_orange" value="&lsaquo;&lsaquo; <?php _e( 'Go Back', APP_TD ); ?>" onclick="history.back()" />
        </div>


<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: It is an HTML entity. `&rsaquo;&rsaquo;` produces `››` See http://www.rsaquo.net/

Comment: its actually not php, it's HTML entity code for right arrow: `›`

Comment: it's an [html entity reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply...  do anyone knows which part of the form does the action process

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All that code to query a character sequence? Well, that's what it is, `&rsaquo;` represents the character `›`. So, the content becomes `Continue ››`. The sequence is parsed from its HTML entity to that. It has nothing strictly to do with PHP *or* Wordpress, just HTML.

In case you find another one and wonder what it does, you can find a full list of these "[HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)" on Wikipedia for example.

Comment: Should downvotes serve to indicate that this is wrong, ...it's not. it answers exactly what is queried in the title, and I hold this to be true until told otherwise.

Comment: thanks for your reply you are exactly correct "Continue>>" is the text/label displayed on the button i was searching for the word continue also... i am accepting this answer as your answer clears part of my doubt

Comment: I do not know people downvote.... please tell the reason and downvote so that i can rectify from next time

Comment: @ Grant Thomas can you tell me how this form is processed which part of the code triggers the form to post the values that are obtained here

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer the actual process that is happening here is multistage form. the hidden input type processes the form here and sends the values to the next page/stage of the form. this is done here to hide the values from the user and process it in next stage